# Shortest way / Shorthand to declare variable in go

Tags: go

We can use the following syntax for go variable declaration

```
var num int
var str string
```

but is there any shorthand in go for doing the same thing?

for example we can do so in python simply saying:

```
num = 13
strings = "Hello World"
```

or even

```
num, strings = 13,"Hello World"
```

Comment: Clear indication of never having done [the Go tour](http://tour.golang.org) which is the first thing you should go through when starting with Go.

Comment: Yes, that's right my apology. Even, just a Google search suffice. Right after posting the question I thought to remove it. But, people in SO are so fast in helping others :D  
I got an answer right after posting. So, thought to keep it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) can initialize multiple variables:

```
var x, y float32 = -1, -2
```

Or (short variable declaration with `:=`)

```
i, j := 0, 10
```

So this would work: [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/ytzTJRKQN5)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := 1, "e"
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground %v %v", b, a)
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, playground e 1
```

Comment: Does the :=  operator have a name?

Comment: @Mercury not really. It used as a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types.

Comment: @VonC well, that's unfortunate.  Thanks, though!  (I'm new to programming in Go-- just trying to pick up all the right jargon...)

Answer (score 1):

The `:=` syntax is shorthand for declaring and initializing a Go variable .
For example:
to declare e string var we can simple use
`str := "Hello world"`

Answer (score 1):

**Short variable declarations**

The := operator is the short variable declaration operator. This operator is used to both declare and initialize a variable.

[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/p43w2nzg5y):

```
   package main

   import "fmt"

   func main() {
     firstName := "Joey"
     fmt.Println(firstName)
   }
```

The variable type is not vital because the Go compiler is able to derive the type based on the value you have assigned. Since we are assigning a string to firstName, firstName is allocated as a variable type as string.